# set gc verbose log from weblogic admin console

Tags: logging, garbage-collection, weblogic

How set
`-XX:PrintGCDetails`
that is garbage collection verbose log using weblogic admin console. Instead of using command prompt. i can set it up by using command prompt but my application want to use UI.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

You can find the answer e.g. in here: [WebLogic Server Performance and Tuning: Part I - Tuning JVM](https://blogs.oracle.com/imc/entry/weblogic_server_performance_and_tuning)

In short, go to `Environment` > `Servers` > `"Your Server Name"` > `Configuration` > `Server Start` > `Arguments`.

Comment: i placed -Xloggc:/bns/gmis/logs/gmis/weblogic_gc.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails in arguments but its not creating the file

Comment: Use e.g. `ps -ef | grep java` to search for the process running your weblogic, its describtion should have the list of JVM args, you can verify whether the GCPrintDetails args are really there.

Comment: Also, use only the -XX:+PrintGCDetails for a start, it will start adding GC info into your default log file.